# Adding startTime and endTime in Calendar Events in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working with Cell Calendar Package. On calendar events I cannot add StartTime and EndTime. How can I add that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There is very little chance that someone can help you if you don't provide enough details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.